# How to implement an interface for different classes of different data types

Tags: java

Say you have an interface which has a `sum` method, with two implementing classes `A` and `B`. Class `A` wants to sum two integers and class `B` wants to sum two long. What will be the implementation of interface `C` ?

```
class A implements C{
sum(2,3);
}

class B implements C {
sum(2.0,3.0);
}
```

How C should be implemented?

Comment: `2.0` and `3.0` are not `long`s...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a generic interface. For Example

```java
    interface C<T extends Number> {
        T sum(T a, T b);
    }

    class A implements C<Long> {

        @Override
        public Long sum(Long a, Long b) {
            return a+b;
        }
    }

    class B implements C<Float> {

        @Override
        public Float sum(Float a, Float b) {
            return a+b;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic interface can help you here. You can extend the `Number` class using Generics in Java

**Interface**

```
public interface BaseInterface<T extends Number> {
    T sum(T a, T b);
}
```

**Integer Implementation**

```
public class ImplementationOne implements BaseInterface<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer sum(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**Double Implementation**

```
public class ImpelementationTwo implements BaseInterface<Double> {
    @Override
    public Double sum(Double a, Double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```